# this.src.indexOf is not a function

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

Sorry i have to ask for help once again but im having trouble with the game engine im running. Im using phaser v3 at the moment but when i load it into a web browser i get the error code

> phaser (1).js:4192 Uncaught TypeError: this.src.indexOf is not a function

I'm unsure on how to get rid of this error and it makes it so i cannot load different assets into the game i am making. This is the code that is giving the error.

```js
this.src = GetURL(this, this.loader.baseURL);

if (this.src.indexOf('data:') === 0) //  error here

{

console.warn('Local data URIs are not supported: ' + this.key);

}

else

{
```

Comment: The error is pretty clear. Whatever `GetURL` returns does not have an `indexOf` function.

Comment: Try this `console.log(this.src);` what do you get?

Comment: See URL result with console.log(this.src)

Comment: @kiranvj it says undefined. Also sorry if this is an obvious anwser but im new to coding and im actively trying to learn.

Comment: What browser are you using? It's unlikely to be `undefined` because if it was, the error message would be different

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Loader.html), the parameters for GetURL is a file(Phaser.Loader.File) and baseURL. Looks like its not correct in your case.

> GetURL(file, baseURL)
>
> Given a File and a baseURL value this returns
> the URL the File will use to download from.

GetURL returns the url of the files. But you are checking for `this.src`

So check

1. Parameters passed to GetURL
2. Check for the return value of GetURL in your `if` condition